# Transform one string to another string

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

**There is a string whose characters can only be either `a`, `b` or `_`,there is only one `_` in the string.**

At each step, we can modify the string as follows:

`_` can be swapped with its adjacent character, example `a_ba` can be changed to either `_aba` or `ab_a`.

You can swap _ character with next to adjacent character only if adjacent character is different from next to adjacent character. (For example `aba_ab` can be converted into `a_abab` or `ababa_`, but `ab_aab` cannot be converted to `abaa_b`, because `a` cannot jump over `a`).

You are given two strings, the initial state and the final state (lengths will be same), you have to output the minimum number of steps required to change the string in initial state to the string in the final state.

example:

```
string s1 ,s2 ;
input: s1 = a_b , s2 = ab_
output: 1
input: s1 = aba_a , s2 = _baaa
output: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved when you think of the problem as a graph problem pretty simply.

The vertices are all the possible states, and there is an edge from two vertices, if you can get from one to the other using a single move.

The problem now, is finding shortest path from source to destination in this graph.

Your code is basically implementing a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on this graph, but DFS is not optimal. You should try implementing a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which is guaranteed to be optimal (always finds the shortest path).

More complex optimizations (for faster running time) include A* search algorithm and bi-directional search, but you should avoid these for now and focus on the simpler BFS, IMHO.

Comment: "The vertices are all the possible states", by states you mean every character in given string. It would be also better if you can provide me pseduo code for this problem. I have spend lot of time on this problem

Comment: Vertices are intermediate strings you generate to transform your string, edges will be operations you apply.

Comment: In EDIT part of question, I have posted the new solution. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how DFS is not optimal?

Comment: @piepi DFS finds **a** path (assuming there is one, and it is not stuck in an infinite branch), not the shortest one.